# Wise using of try / catch

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

I hope this topic won't be too philosophical :)

Generally I'm developing an application where there is a lot of connecting with outer world.
You save and read from files, you connect to databases, read packets coming through TCP protocol, send printing tasks to printers, parse user text input and so on. Every one of these operations may theoretically go wrong in many possible ways.

My problem is that I'm tired of writing try/catch blocks for hundreds of instructions. It makes code twice as long, much worse to read and instead of doing some "real" coding I keep on writing  messages to the log that will probably never happen.

But is there any other choice?

What is your approach? Make all these try/catch blocks? Or just ignore these possible errors and deal with ACTUAL errors only after an user reports them?

Should we never allow application to crash, should we predict any stupid action by an user or is it user problem not to do stupid actions?

And is it better to put big blocks of code into try/catch or put single instructions into it?

I'd be grateful for any advice or just opinion.

Comment: What kind of exceptions to you catch? Can you show some sample code?

Comment: This all depends on what your code is doing, etc. etc. there are many variables in this type of decision.

Comment: On another note, you should really accept a few answers. People will be more likely to help if you do.

Comment: >It's helps to shown your system exception , Press ctrl+D,E and see the unhandled exceptions details. This error was handled by try catch 

>In My opinion is It's bad !!! You can manually define any errors with code.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use Exceptions if a part of your code is likely to break.

Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances!

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) suggests a couple of sensible alertnatives, namely the Tester-Doer pattern and the Try-Parse pattern.

Comment: Not sure how to avoid exceptions for network-driven code. It does not sound like he's using them for control flow.

Comment: Exceptions have their place, of course - that's why they exist, but the OP does say "parse user text input and so on" as well though...

Answer (score 1):

You should write the `try` around those parts that can actually fail. Those are usually the network operations themselves, not all the other code around them. If you `try`-protect too much code you risk catching exceptions that are *not* network errors, but your code might mistake them as such.

If you do have to `try`-protect many lines (maybe because you are doing fine-grained reads with a `BinaryReader`) you can put the contents of the `try` into a separate method. That gets rid of the indenting and hides a lot of complexity. Resharper can extract methods very easily.

You need a top-level exception handler anyway to log unexpected errors that are usually bugs. Those do happen as well.

Only catch when you can reasonably handle the error, or you log that specific error and rethrow. I find that in most circumstances I need very few `catch` handlers because most errors cannot be deal with except by aborting the process.